# selecting multiple Radio buttons with the same name

Tags: html, forms, listview, radio-button

the radio buttons in the code below have the same name, but i can still select more than one button
I don't wont it to happan.

```
<asp:ListView ID="BuyM" runat="server" DataKeyNames="kod" >
    <LayoutTemplate>

        <table dir="rtl" style="border:1px solid black;background-color:#E6CCFF;" >
            <tr class="header">
                <td>dsg</td>
                <td>dfg</td>
                <td>dfg</td>
                <td>fgd</td>
                <td>dfg</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder></tr>
        </table>

    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="row">
            <th>
                   <input type="radio" id="rb" runat="server" name="rb" value='<%# Eval("kod") %>' />
            </th>
            <th>
                <%# Eval("kod") %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%# Eval("nameE") %>
            </th>
            <th>

                <%# Eval("Sk") %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%# Eval("groupN") %>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr class="alterRow">
            <th>
                <input type="radio" id="rb" runat="server"  name="rb" value='<%# Eval("kod") %>' />
            </th>
            <th>
                <%# Eval("kod") %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%# Eval("nameE") %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%# Eval("Sk") %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%# Eval("groupN") %>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        no records found
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView></div>
```

how do i fix it?(it work fine untill i added the runat="server" and the value)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use same IDs for multiple elements. The names can be equal but never the same ID. Also verify if radio buttons are contained in the same form.

Comment: the radio buttons are contained in the same form.Furthermore, i tried to change the id of one of the radio buttons but it didn't help too, i still can select more than one radio button.